# borderRadius for rangeBar at apexCharts for boths sides of bar

Tags: apex, apexcharts

I am trying to achieve a borderRadius for the bars at boths sides.
The option "borderRadius" at the plotOption is just making the borders at the end of the bar round.

```
var options = {
        series: [],
        chart: {
          height: 500,
          type: 'rangeBar'
        },
        plotOptions: {
          bar: {
            horizontal: true,
            distributed: false,
            **borderRadius: 10,**
            dataLabels: {
              hideOverflowingLabels: false
            },
          },
        },
        xaxis: {
          type: 'datetime',
          labels: {
            format: 'dd MMM',
          }
        },
        yaxis: {
          show: true,
        },
        grid: {
          row: {
            colors: ['#f3f4f5', '#fff'],
            opacity: 1
          }
        },
        stroke: {
          width: 0.5,
          lineCap: 'rounded',
          colors: ['var(--color-grey-medium)']
        },
      };
```

I tried to contact the support and searched the whole documentation, but cannot find a solution